# What happened to the Dothraki loyal to Daenerys?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of *Game of Thrones* season 1, the Dothraki were supposed to make a choice on whether or not to follow Daenerys. And in season 2, some of them made the choice to betray her, but I don't suppose all of them?

Now, in season 5, we see the Unsullied and the Second Sons, but not any Dothraki followers. Did I forget some part of the series maybe?

Comment: I believe a lot of them died at Qarth when Xaro Xhoan Daxos betrays Daenerys

Comment: You can actually quite clearly see two in series five when they drag Mossador onto the platform to be executed. However Dany says to Missandei that she is out of practice with speaking Dothraki, suggesting that she doesn't talk to them much. Remember she did try to sell them into slavery at Astapor.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They are still around, but there were never that many of them to begin with, so they are fading into the background. In the screen shot below, form when Danaerys first arrives in Qarth, you can see the entire khalasar with her.

[image]

If you watch the recent scenes with Dany in them, you'll occasionally see a Dothraki extra mixed in, mostly in her Queen's Guard. But the number of Unsullied is far, far greater than the number of Dothraki around her, plus the others in Dany's "court" she's picked up along the way. So the Dothraki are just not that prominent.

Comment: Came here to answer, then I realise that @Mike is just too fast! +1

Comment: Do you know if the actors playing the most recognisable of Dany's dothraki are still employed in season 5? e.g. the handmaidens and the bloodrider with the whip (I don't remember their names). I wonder if those actors might have moved on to other things while the characters' roles in series 5 were deemed too minor to confuse the viewers by introducing new actors. Can prob be looked up on imdb but I'm not sure how

Comment: You forgot to mention that most of them got killed in Qarth.

Answer (score 0):

The show is inconsistent with their numbers. Episode 7 of Season 2 she seemed to be down to a single Dothraki (Kovarro). She later has at least a couple of dozen [when sailing for Astapor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nR9rzXWK96A), later still she [seems to have a couple of hundred](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1pPQwXsZx0) after obtaining the unsullied army.

Either way they are small enough in number to not be considered either militarily or politically a significant force in Mereen.

Answer (score 0):

She has about 35 or so that enter Mereen with her. I'm sure a few would have got killed in the Harpy insurgency but I think it would also be the case that there would be some Khal-unaffiliated Dothraki in the city serving as Guards, in the fighting pits, in the sellsword companies. There would also be some exile dothraki around, those who fled the destruction of a khalasar or having gotten on the wrong side of a Khal. The khalasar of Drogo broke up into several groups so word of Dany would have spread amongst the Dothraki. I'm sure some young men who could never hope to rise in status in some of the big khalasars might have decided to ride to Mereen to see her/join her. Her exploits in Qarth, Astapor etc would also have got back to the Dothraki Plains encouraging some to go join her. All in all it is reasonable to think as her legend grew some more Dothraki would have begun to join her even before the great conflagration taking out the Great Khals.